# How do I add an object to an empty user interface file?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xib

In Xcode, I created a new file (and opened it) with the "Empty" user interface template.

How do I add a tab bar controller to it? When I try to drag & drop one onto the design canvas, it floats back to the Object library.

I want to create a `.xib` file, not a `.storyboard` file, to use as my launch screen. I can't use the "Launch Screen" template because that creates a `.storyboard` file.

Comment: i think you must choose 'View" and not "Empty", if you want to add a tab bar, it make a `.xib` file

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by restarting my Mac.